# How to resolve the Keypad hides after typing the key in TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I type the 1st letter in keyboards it goes off and hides how to resolve this scenario I'm using
many text form fields within a page  with keyboard Focus, custom font, max length,onEditingComplete, onTap properties

Sample Code:

```
              TextFormField(
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        focusNode: myfocus,
                        controller: mycontroller,
                        maxLength: 500,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontSize: 14
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          counterText: "",
                          labelText: name,
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                        onEditingComplete: () =>
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(secondFocus),
                        onTap: () {
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                        }, )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` from onTap

```
onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        }
```

Comment: when I click outside the keypad it needs to close that's why I'm using this onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        }